# How to pass an array of random numbers to random.choice while defining a function?

Tags: python, random, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to a write a python code to calculate randomly stopped sum, but encounter problem when size of the randomly generated numbers is going beyond 5.

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 15.5 PiB for an array with shape (49, 53, 43, 46, 52, 53, 57, 52, 52) and data type float64

in the following code:

```
#Create a function tn.func to calculate randomly stopped sum
import numpy as np
#Define a function
def tn_fun(n):
    return sum(np.random.choice([50, 100, 200], n, replace=True, p=[0.3, 0.5, 0.2]))
N = np.random.poisson(50, 10)
# #Generate 10000 random values of N, using lambda = 50
TN = tn_fun(N)
print('Sample mean of the randomly stopped sum TN is',np.mean(TN))
print('Sample variance of the randomly stopped sum TN is', np.var(TN))
```

Comment: I don' think you understand what you are asking for.  The second parameter to `np.random.choice` is the size of the matrix you want it to create.  If you pass it [100,100,100], it will create a 100x100x100 array.  What were you expecting that to do?

Comment: [link to the doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

Comment: I would say use numpy.memmap but not sure how big you HDD should be for 15PiB and don't lnow hob big mmemapp can handle

Comment: Looking at your comments, perhaps you expected [50,100,200] to be the size of the array. If so, you need to swap the first two parameters.  Of course, that means your `p` array no longer matches the shape of the input.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am trying to find sum of n observations, where n is also random in nature. That’s way I generated n from Poisson distribution. While passing this randomly generated n to the argument, I am facing problems in order to compute sample mean and sample variance of TN.

Comment: N will have 10 random values.  It's trivial to compute the sum and variance of those values.  Why are you using `random.choice` at all?  How does it provide value here?

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried and faced the above error continuously when N was greater than 5. random.choice provide a sample of desired size that way I used it to define the function.

Comment: Your `tn_fun` is clearly wrong.  It's generating a HUGE number of samples, and then returning a simple sum as a single integer.   You can't take the mean and variance of a simple sum.  What, exactly, do you expect `tn_fun` to return?  Describe it in words.

Comment: @TimRoberts tn should return here a sum of n observations, where n is also random.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you seem to be asking for.

```
import numpy as np

# How many samples should there be?

# This is uniform between 5000 and 15000.
#N = np.random.randint(5000, 15000)

# This picks one number with Poisson distribution centered at 10000.
N = np.random.poisson(10000, 1)[0]

# Generate them.

TN = np.random.choice( [50,100,200], N, p=[0.3,0.5,0.2] )

print('Sample mean of the randomly stopped sum TN is',np.mean(TN))
print('Sample variance of the randomly stopped sum TN is', np.var(TN))
```

Comment: I am trying to find a truncated sum $T_N = X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_N$, where $X_1, X_2, . . .X_N$ are N observations and independent of each other as well of N. $X_i \in \{50, 100, 200\}$ with probability distribution $\{0.3, 0.5, 0.2\}$.

Comment: OK, then your KEY flaw was in generating N.  You just want N to be a SINGLE NUMBER indicating how many samples you want.  Your code was generating N as an array of 10 elements.   I've modified my code.

Comment: Rightly pointed. The problem is resolved now. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is resolved now for N=np.random.randint(5000, 15000), but it is not working for N = np.random.poisson(50, 10000).

Comment: Of COURSE not, because those do two entirely different things!  The first generates ONE number in that range.  The second generates 10,000 numbers.  You don't want `poisson` here.  Have you read the documentation for `np.random.poisson`?  Have you looked at what it produces?

Comment: Perhaps what you want is `N = np.random.poisson( 10000,1 )[0]`.